# Android Dynamic View Positioning

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need `view2` to be next to `view1` if `view1` is not filling the whole width.
If the content of `view1` is full width (the content fills whole width of screen) then `view2` should be under it.

For example if my `TextView` text is short a timestamp be next to it
If `TextView` text is multiline the time stamp be under it

Can I achieve this using ConstraintLayout?

[When view1 is not full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f76PE.png)

[When view1 is full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hB2g.png)

Comment: Please check my answer may this helps you.

Comment: Check updated answer if  still issue then let me know.. right now leaving from office.
if it's helpful answer then please mark as a right answer : https://www.google.com/search?q=mark+as+a+right+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNTCC3PUsWbrEz8yHfTOmj-8izquvA:1578751128985&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0lu2h2vvmAhWDoOkKHa-cCDIQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1517&bih=675#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Comment: Two possibilities: _ConstraintLayout_ [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) or [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Comment: @Cheticamp Flexbox was the option to go. thanks for your practical answer.

Comment: @InsaneCat I'm sorry, but your answer didn't help me. I even tried it and it was not even close.

Comment: Ok then i'm gonna delete it tahks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but, i recommend use the Constraint Layout in head but a other layout (Relative or Recycle) to organize the other elements from view.

You can use a custom width, if you are a sure the position.
Or, still, you can try use "parent", if you divide in fragments the wrap content works too.